# how to change horizontali textview scroll direction in xamarin android

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

hi so i was working on an calculator app so for textview in need to scroll it from right to left but its only working ltr what can i do?

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        
        
        
        >

        <TextView
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
        
        
        
        />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `FocusSearchDirection.Right` to make the textview start scrolling from right to left.

```
      <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#007b12"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <TextView
        android:text="zzzzzzzzzzzzzzztfytytytytytytytytytytytytgjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjiylhnhjk7fj"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Code behind:

```
   var scrollview = FindViewById<HorizontalScrollView>(Resource.Id.ScrollView);
        scrollview.PostDelayed(new Runnable(()=>
        {
            scrollview.FullScroll(FocusSearchDirection.Right);
        }), 100L);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately its not working if you want to add the letters and numbers by user and in the app..its only working if you want to create a constant text or image:(

Comment: oh no wait sorry i made a mistakeat fist i placed your code behind in oncreate method.. thank you so much